Salesforce Data Cloud Web SDK
We earlier used Data Cloud web SDK connector to track interactions on the website and store in data in Data Cloud's Data Lake Objects(DLO's). Does Web SDK connector provides any feasibility to use this interaction data and personalised the content on the webiste?
If so, is there any detailed document which guides on this implementation?
If not, is there any supporting document which says it is not feasible with Web SDK connector?

Yes, Data Cloud Web SDK can now customize websites in real time with the newly introduced feature in July'24 release. Please find the below link to the same.
Link:- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_cdp_2024_summer_realtime_limited_GA.htm&release=250&type=5
